# Why are my images not loading from Shazam Core API in my React app using React-Redux and React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router, shazam

My images are not pulling from shazam core API

This is my Song Card Component:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import PlayPause from "./PlayPause";
import { playPause, setActiveSong } from "../redux/features/playerSlice";

const SongCard = (song, i) => {
  const activeSong = "test";

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col w-[250px] p-4 bg-white/5 bg-opacity-80 backdrop-slur-sm animate-slideup rounded-lg cursor-pointer">
      <div className="relative w-full h-56 group">
        <div
          className={`absolute inset-0 justify-center items-center bg-black bg-opacity-50 group-hover:flex ${
            activeSong?.title === song.title
              ? 'flex bg-black bg-opacity-70'
              : 'hidden'
          }`}
        >
          <PlayPause />
        </div>
        <img alt="song_img" src={song.images?.coverart} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SongCard;
```

This is my Discover Component that's using the Song Card Component

```
import { Error, Loader, SongCard } from "../components";
import { genres } from "../assets/constants";
import { useGetTopChartsQuery } from "../redux/services/shazamCore";

const Discover = () => {
  const { data, isFetching, error } = useGetTopChartsQuery();

  const genreTitle = "Pop";

  if (isFetching) return <Loader title="Loading Songs.." />;
  if (error) return <Error />;
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <div className="w-full flex justify-between items-center sm:flex-row flex-col mt-4 mb-10">
        <h2 className="font-bold text-3xl text-white text-left">
          Discover {genreTitle}
        </h2>
        <select
          onChange={() => {}}
          value=""
          className="bg-black text-gray-300 p-3 text-sm rounded-lg outline-none sm:mt-0 mt-5 "
        >
          {genres.map((genre) => (
            <option key={genre.value} value={genre.value}>
              {genre.title}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-wrap sm:justify-start justify-center gap-8">
        {data.map((song, i) => (
          <SongCard key={song.key} song={song} i={i} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Discover;
```

Answer (score 1):

React components accept a single props object, you have declared `Song` to accept two arguments and named the props object `song`. As such you'd need to destructure the passed `song` and `i` props from the `song` props object, e.g. `song.song` and `song.i`.

It's probably better to rename the props object from `song` to the more standard `props` name. Even better to just destructure the `song` and `i` props directly.

Assuming the `song.images.coverart` prop value is correct this should be all you need to update.

Also, since `i`, as a prop, doesn't appear to be referenced or used in `SongCard` I've removed it.

```
const SongCard = ({ song }) => { // <-- destructure from props object
  const activeSong = "test";

  return (
    <div className="....">
      <div className="relative w-full h-56 group">
        <div
          className={`.... ${
            activeSong?.title === song.title
              ? 'flex bg-black bg-opacity-70'
              : 'hidden'
          }`}
        >
          <PlayPause />
        </div>
        <img alt="song_img" src={song.images?.coverart} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SongCard;
```